# ConTeXt customize styling similar to CSS

Tags: context, css

In html, one can `<div class, id>` and CSS styling with selection based on "class" or "id". Is it possible to do it similarly in ConTeXt?

For example, using "define" then "setup", then "start/stop"? From the document, I can see that one can define/customize "head". How about an arbitrary piece of text?

Comment: It’s not exactly classes or id”s, but [``\definehighlight``](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definehighlight) may be what you’re looking for.

Comment: `\definehighlight` and `\definestartstop`. Also look at Wolfgang Schuster's annotation module.

Answer (score 3):

`\definestartstop` is what you're looking for.

```
\definestartstop
  [cssselectorexample]
  [style=italic]

\starttext

Hello
\startcssselectorexample
  Foo Bar Baz
\stopcssselectorexample
World

\stoptext
```