# How to understand LaTeX styling when coming from a CSS background?

Tags: floats, positioning, css

I come from a web development background and I am used to apply CSS styles to HTML tags in order to position and shape them. In LaTeX I constantly find myself trying to think in terms of CSS and of how things are 'supposed' to float, move, or expand as I play around with content and style. However, my preconceived notions that come from this CSS knowledge often give predict the outcome poorly. I find myself generating PDFs frequently in order to understand how new code impacts the result. Surely I am unable to let go of particular ideas, but I just find that LaTeX floats boxes very oddly, and thatit is *very* difficult to put things in my position of choice.

The question is: can someone who was also used to work with CSS explain common pitfalls and suggest ideas for thinking differently about LaTeX and making things make 'more sense'?

Comment: I think the most important "pitfall" is that TeX breaks things into "real" pages, while CSS/HTML doesn't. This means "floats" in each case are quite different.  As your document is not described, it is hard to suggest anything concrete that will help.  Perhaps, though: *don't* float things if you have very concrete ideas about where things go. (See, e.g., the package [textpos](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos); and the [layout](http://www.ctan.org/topic/layout) category on CTAN.)

Comment: [Related](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6461/34551)

Comment: A better analogy between TeX and HTML based techniques is the `<tr>` and `<td>` tags of an HTML table which, very roughly(!), correspond to the horizontal and vertical modes of TeX box stacking.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it can help,

Mainly, we are talking about completely different things here, the main difference being **pages**.

When you talk about LaTeX, you are really thinking in printing your work in paper (or at least a PDF), but in CSS, it is a fluid bunch of objects floating in the **web page**

Please take a look at [this article](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwjsgO-KkbbHAhWBsh4KHVV_BFM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fyihui.name%2Fen%2F2013%2F10%2Fmarkdown-or-latex%2F&ei=5frUVaz6C4HletX-kZgF&usg=AFQjCNGhMG8JZGLmQ54L4eueo8_EG-U3tg&sig2=e5oZytZ-_5cniGbYaFxYFA&bvm=bv.99804247,d.dmo)

Comment: This just looks like Jon's comment with the addition of a link.